Contradiction: Exact sequence of constant sheaves, but not exact when using long exact sequence?
So, I'm again trying to understand the statement made in Masaki Kashiwara's and Pierre Schapira's book "Sheaves on Manifolds" that I describe in the post: Why is $ \mathfrak{Mod}(A_{Y}/f) $
a thick subcategory of $\mathfrak{Mod}(A_{Y})$
?
Through trying to work this out, I came across a contradiction in my thinking, which I can't seem to resolve:
Take two abelian groups $N,M$ and consider the exact sequence $$0 \to N \to N \oplus M \to M \to 0$$
This can be taken as a (exact) sequence of presheaves over a topological space $X$.
This induces a sequence with the associated constant sheaves:
$$0 \to N_{X} \to (N \oplus M)_{X} \to M_{X} \to 0$$
which is exact. But, if we take $U \subset X$ connected, since $\Gamma(U; N_{X}) = N$, $\Gamma(U; M_{X}) = M$ and $\Gamma(U; (N \oplus M)_{X}) = N \oplus M$. So, "at $U$", the sequence is also exact.
Alternatively, I could have applied the long exact sequence property and: $$0 \to N \to N \oplus M \to M \to H^{1}(U; N_{X}) \to...$$ would also be exact, but now $H^{1}(U; N_{X}) \neq 0$ in general, which would lead to a contradiction.
For example, we could take $X = \mathbb{S}^{1}$, $N = \mathbb{R}$ and $M = \mathbb{R}$. Then, $H^{1}(\mathbb{S}^{1}; \mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{S}^{1}}) \neq 0$. In fact, we have a c-soft resolution (which is $\Gamma(\mathbb{S}^{1}; \bullet)$-acyclic, since $\mathbb{S}^{1}$ is locally compact and countable at infinity): $$ 0 \to \mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{S}^{1}} \to \Omega^{0}_{\mathbb{S}^{1}} \overset{d}{\to} \Omega^{1}_{\mathbb{S}^{1}} \overset{d}{\to}...$$
So, $$H^{1}(\mathbb{S}^{1}; \mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{S}^{1}}) = \dfrac{\text{ker}(\Omega^{1}_{\mathbb{S}^{1}} \overset{d}{\to} \Omega^{2}_{\mathbb{S}^{1}})}{\text{im}(\Omega^{0}_{\mathbb{S}^{1}} \overset{d}{\to} \Omega^{1}_{\mathbb{S}^{1}})}$$.
and we at least have the 1-form $\omega = i^{*}(xdy -ydx)$, $i: \mathbb{S}^{1} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ which satisfies $\omega \in \text{ker}(\Omega^{1}_{\mathbb{S}^{1}} \overset{d}{\to} \Omega^{2}_{\mathbb{S}^{1}})$ but $\omega \notin \text{im}(\Omega^{0}_{\mathbb{S}^{1}} \overset{d}{\to} \Omega^{1}_{\mathbb{S}^{1}})$.
So, there must be some mistake lying around in here. Could you point me out what is wrong?
Thank you all in advance :)

Your contradiction is resolved by the fact that the connecting map $M \to H^1(U;N_X)$ is zero.

Right... Thank you for the observation. Can't believe I didn't see that
